Missing initials in op. cit
I'm writting my thesis from economics and have quite strictly defined editting requirements. I spend past two days configuring biblatex to work the way I want but I stuck with adding initials to the op. cit. foot citations. I copy-pasted lots of solutions from the Internet and various LLM answers without success. Unfortunately, the biblatex documentation is quite hard to navigate (362 pages as of November 2024). I put lots of comments to my code, so it is easier to express what I wanted to achieve. I'll be thankful for valuable advices. Thanks.
What I want to achieve summary:
The op. cit. foot citations contain: {authors initials}. {family names}, {title}, op. cit., s. {pages}
This is what I have (as of MWE):

This is what I want to achieve (note highlighted initials):

MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[
citestyle=verbose-trad2,% Full bib entry in footcite + ibidem + opcit.
bibstyle=verbose,
ibidpage=true,          % Skip pages for the same footcite
pagetracker=false,      % Use Ibidem for all (even if source footcite is on the previous page)
giveninits=true,        % Use initials instead of full name
sorting=nyt,            % Sort bibliography by name, year, title
]{biblatex}             % Advanced control over bibliography
% Replace "Tamże" (Polish term) with "Ibidem"
\DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{%
    ibidem = {Ibidem},
    opcit = {op\adddotspace cit\adddot}
}
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}      % Italics Ibidem and op. cit.
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}   % Remove comma between the family and initials
% Separator between authors
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % comma space between consecutive authors
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % comma space for last author
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % Family goes before initials

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

sem\autocite[12]{osterwalder2022}
sem\autocite[13]{osterwalder2022}
sem\autocite[14]{osterwalder2022}
sem\autocite[55]{gierszewska2017}
sem\autocite[14]{osterwalder2022}
sem\autocite[14]{osterwalder2022}
sem\autocite[15]{osterwalder2022}
sem\autocite[55]{gierszewska2017}
sem\autocite[16]{osterwalder2022}
sem\autocite[80]{gierszewska2017}
sem\autocite[105]{fisher2004}
sem\autocite[115]{fisher2004}
sem\autocite[16]{osterwalder2022}
sem\autocite[150]{fisher2004}
sem\autocite[400]{trocki2012}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

Edit: My bibliography.bib file:
@book{osterwalder2022,
  author    = {Alexander Osterwalder and Yves Pigneur},
  title     = {Tworzenie modeli biznesowych},
  publisher = {Wydawnictwo Onepress},
  year      = {2022}
}

@book{gierszewska2017,
  author    = {Grażyna Gierszewska and Maria Romanowska},
  title     = {Analiza strategiczna przedsiębiorstwa},
  publisher = {Polskie Wydawnictwo Ekonomiczne},
  edition   = {Wydanie V zmienione},
  address   = {Warszawa},
  year      = {2017}
}

@book{trocki2012,
  editor    = {Michał Trocki},
  title     = {Nowoczesne zarządzanie projektami},
  publisher = {Polskie Wydawnictwo Ekonomiczne},
  address   = {Warszawa},
  year      = {2012}
}

@book{fisher2004,
  author    = {Roger Fisher and William Ury and Bruce Patton},
  title     = {Dochodząc do tak},
  publisher = {Polskie Wydawnictwo Ekonomiczne},
  edition   = {Wydanie II},
  address   = {Warszawa},
  year      = {2004}
}


well you didn't provide a bib (and there is a command missing in your options) but you can try to redefine the labelname format \DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%   \usebibmacro{name:given-family}         {\namepartfamily}         {\namepartgiveni}         {\namepartprefix}         {\namepartsuffixi}%   \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

Hi, thanks for sharing. I've eddited the original question with the bib file contents. What do you mean by command is missing in options?

sorry I meant a comma not a command. And did you try my suggestion?

Oh, now I see a missing comma. Just tried your code. It worked like a charm. Thank you very much. The documentation of this package is so generic, that I couldn't find the solution to my needs. Good to have places like that one (stackexchange) ;)
